# Not getting SourceContext property in the LogEvent param of Emit method in my custom sink serilog c#

Tags: c#, .net-core, serilog

I have created a custom sink. I have created the usage using both approaches: API as well as configuration.
But I am not able to get the SourceContext property in the LogEvent param of Emit method in my custom sink.

```
"Serilog":{
      "Using":[ "ConsoleApp3" ],
      "MinimumLevel":"Debug",
      "Enrich":[
         "FromLogContext"
      ],
      "WriteTo": [
            {
              "Name": "ConsoleApp3",
              "Args": {
                "outputTemplate": "{Message:lj}{}{NewLine}{Exception}"
              }
            }
          ]
   }

var logger = new LoggerConfiguration().ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
                     .WriteTo.MySink(DefaultOutputTemplate)
                     .CreateLogger();
```

OR

```
var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .MinimumLevel.Debug()
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .WriteTo.MySink(DefaultOutputTemplate)
                .CreateLogger();

public class MySink : ILogEventSink
    {
        private readonly ITextFormatter m_TextFormatter;

        public MySink(ITextFormatter textFormatter)
        {
            m_TextFormatter = textFormatter;
        }

        public void Emit(LogEvent logEvent) ------> not getting here
        {
            string entry = string.Empty;
            using (StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter())
            {
                m_TextFormatter.Format(logEvent, stringWriter);
                entry = stringWriter.ToString();
            }

            Console.WriteLine(entry);
        }
    }

    public static class MySinkExtensions
    {
        public static LoggerConfiguration MySink(
                  this LoggerSinkConfiguration loggerConfiguration,
                   string outputTemplate,
                  IFormatProvider formatProvider = null)
        {
            var textFormatter = new MessageTemplateTextFormatter(outputTemplate, formatProvider);
            return loggerConfiguration.Sink(new MySink(textFormatter));
        }
    }
```

Now what I may be missing that SourceContext property is missing the Properties dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

`Enrich.FromLogContext()` has nothing to do with the `SourceContext` - [you need to do `PushContext` for that mechanism to add values to your `LogEvent`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Enrichment).

`SourceContext` is normally established through the `ForContext` extension method (search [in this cheatsheet](https://benfoster.io/blog/serilog-best-practices))

Note that none of this has anything to do with custom sinks - you should be able to validate these facts using only the Console sink